# Complex regex to check for two words and a quanity

Tags: regex

Ok what I'm trying to do is to check for the presence of

- "TestItem-1"
- a number greater then 1
- one of the possible words in the list of "KG. Kg, kg, Kilo(s) or Kilogram(s)"

Where any of the items could be in any order and within a 6 word limit of each other.

Has to be done in regex as there is no access to the underlying scripting engine

This is what I've got as there a way of checking greater then I decided to use a range of 1-999 for the number check.

```
\b(?:[T|t]estItem-1\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}(^[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$)\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}[K|k]il[o|os]|[K|k][[G|GS]|[g|gs]]|[|K|k]ilogra[m|ms]\b
```

Examples of what I need to find would be like -

> "TestItem-1 is unstable in quanties above 12 Kilograms"
>   "1 Kilogram of TestItem-1"

While I wouldn't want to find -

> "15 units of TestItem-1"

I know that what I got isn't working each section appears to work independently of each other but not together.

I pass this over to far greater minds then mine :)

Comment: Oops I think I edited at the same time you did and it rollbacked your edit! Feel free to re-edit it ! (and sorry)

Comment: **Where any of the items could be in any order and with a 6 word limit of each other.** This is a bit unclear, do you mean that `TestItem-1`, `The number n > 1` and a form of `kilo`. Can be anywhere in the string? e.g. "*26 Units of TestItem-1 KG*"? If that's the case you could probably use 3 lookaheads to verify that each component is in the string.

Comment: @rvalvik Yes, however it is assumed that normal english language rules would be followed, so the number would come before the list item, such as "15 Kilo", "5 Kgs" or "10 Kilograms". Lookaheads don't appear to be supported in the system I'm cursed with doing this in.

Comment: @MikeM could be in any order and within 6 words of each other.  So, Kilograms could be before or after TestItem-1 as long as it was within the 6 word limit it would be a match outside that no match would be required.  This is the clients instructions to match they're compliance guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
\b(?:[2-9]|\d\d+)\b\s\b(?:KG.|Kg,|kg,|Kilos?|Kilograms?)\b(?:\S+\s){0,6}\bTestItem-1\b|\bTestItem-1\b(?:\S+\s){0,6}\b(?:[2-9]|\d\d+)\b\s\b(?:KG.|Kg,|kg,|Kilos?|Kilograms?)\b
```

Not ideal with the duplication but without lookarounds that's the best I could think of. I'll try and improve it in a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll run the test data over that one and let you know

Comment: Updated to take the 6 words in between criteria. I'm assuming a "word" is constituted by **one or more non space characters followed by a whitespace character**

Comment: It is and it's worked with the test data this morning and now I've seen how I've been able to modifiy it to fit the other test's that were needed to match the client.  So a big thank you